# Operações com matrizes em C++

Tags: array, c++, matriz

Para realizar a soma de itens de uma matriz(diagonal primária e diagonal secundária) eu consegui escrever o seguinte código. Alguém pode me ajudar a deixar o código mais enxuto? para que eu compare os códigos... C++:
E gostaria de saber se há alguma função para esse tipo problema...

(Pode ser com outras bibliotecas que não seja)

```
int main()
{
int matriz[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3},
                    {4, 5, 6},
                    {7, 8, 9}};

        int somaP = 0;
        for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 3; i++, j++)
        {
               somaP += matriz[i][i];
        }
        cout << somaP << endl;

        int somaS = 0;
        for(int x = 0, y = 2; (x < 3) && (y > -1); x++, y--)
            {
                somaS += matriz[x][y];
            }
        cout << somaS << endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Comparar com o que?

Comment: não era pra comparar, apenas para realizar a soma da diagonal prim. e depois da secund.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá para fazer tudo num só `for` calculando as duas coisas simultaneamente. E ter apenas uma condição pois quando o `i` termina o `j` também termina.

Pode então ficar assim:

```
int main()
{
    int matriz[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3},
                    {4, 5, 6},
                    {7, 8, 9}};

    int somaP = 0, somaS = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)  //quando i termina j também terminava
    {
        somaP += matriz[i][i];
        somaS += matriz[i][3-1-i]; //este corresponde ao seu antigo y--, que decresce
    }

    cout << somaP << endl;
    cout << somaS << endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Clareou a ideia. Agora estou tentando assimilar a logica matemática do [3-1-i].

Comment: @ElderSon eu pus `3-1-i` propositadamente, para ser claro que é `tamanho-1-i`. Se quiser simplificar pode por `2-i`. O ultimo elemento é `tamanho-1` logo se você vai no `2` elemento, o `2` do fim será o `ultimo-2`, logo será `tamanho-1-2`. Se não for muito claro é só dizer que eu complemento a resposta com esse detalhe.

Comment: Agora sim, foi mais explicativo, bro ! ;D

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um código aqui, ficou bem mais simples, não tem muito o que explicar:

```
int matriz[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3},
                    {4, 5, 6},
                    {7, 8, 9}};

int somaP = 0, somaS = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    somaP += matriz[i][i];
    somaS += matriz[i][2-i];
}

cout << somaP << endl << somaS;
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/5zE1OJ).

Comment: very nice,man !!

Comment: @ElderSon Caso a resposta esteja certa, por favor marque-a como correta.